# Ng-switch embedded in custom directive not getting evaluated when value changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-switch

I created a custom directive that's basically a reusable form.  Part of the form is an error message display that uses `ng-switch`:

```html
<div ng-switch="status">
  <span ng-switch-when="Error" class="text-error">Error encountered</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="Verifying" class="text-info">Verifying</span>
  <span ng-switch-when="Success" class="text-success">Success</span>
  <span ng-switch-default>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

In my directive's controller, I defined a function that performs verification with the server:

```
$scope.verify = function () {
   $scope.status = 'verifying';
   socket.emit('verify', $scope.data, function(result) {
     $scope.status = result;
   });
};
```

This function is then called by the `link` function on blur event of an input box.

What I am noticing is that the "Verifying" state never shows up, but the "Error"/"Success" states work fine.  It seems that AngularJS is processing the `ng-switch` directive only after my current directive has completed processing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Is there a way for me to get around this behaviour so that the verifying state would show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is changing before Angular has completed the `$digest` cycle and rendered the view. Try calling `emit` asynchronously via `$timeout`, which will allow the framework to render the current view and then update it later when your data is finished loading:

```
$scope.verify = function () {
   function afterLoading(){
       socket.emit('verify', $scope.data, function(result) {
           $scope.status = result;
       });
   }
   $scope.status = 'verifying';
   $timeout(afterLoading, 0);
};
```

(Also remember to inject the `$timeout` service in your controller)